# How can I make a method with parameters creating an instance in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

so I'm a newbie learning 'bout classes and object orienting in java. Each instance of a mobile saves the model, owner name and number. So in the main file I try to make a method with those parameters and an identifier to create a new instance. However, compiling says that mobName already is defined within createMobile. It's supposed to make an instance which can be pointed to using "mob1". Any help?

```
class PhoneSystem{

     public static void main(String[] args){

            createMobile("mob1", "Android S4", "John Doe", 13374042);
        }

        public static void createMobile(String mobName, String brand, String owner, int number){
            Mobile mobName = new Mobile();
            mobName.SetBrand(brand);
            mobName.SetOwner(owner);
            mobName.SetNumber(number);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static void createMobile(String mobName, String brand, String owner, int number){
        Mobile mobName = new Mobile();
    ...
```

These two lines are where your problem resides. You have defined a `String mobName`. Afterwards, you attempt to define a variable with the same name as `Mobile mobName`. Variables cannot share the same name, even within method declaration and method. There's a unique case where this is possible, but that involves fields and instances and is beyond the scope of this question.

Since you want `mob1` you should do:

```
        Mobile mob1 = new Mobile();
```

Additionally, you have not specified if you want `mob1` to be its name or its variable name. If you want the device to be known as `mob1` you should probably make it so `Mobile` takes a device name as String. There's another way to associate the `Mobile` instance with a name via `Map` but since you're saying you're learning OO, that may also be outside of scope as it involves `Collection`.

However, the current code you've provided would result in mob1 going out of scope at the end of the method. Perhaps you wanted to `return` it to the main class?

```
    public static Mobile createMobile(String mobName, String brand, String owner, int number){
        Mobile mob1 = new Mobile();
    ...
        return mob1;
    }
```

This would allow you to create `mob1` and pass it to your main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void createMobile(String mobileName, String brand, String owner, int number){
            Mobile mobName = new Mobile();
            mobName.SetBrand(brand);
            mobName.SetOwner(owner);
            mobName.SetNumber(number);
        }
```

Here createMobile method first arg name and mobile object name are same that why u got error